# STOMP planner: Can only handle joint space goals

Tags: ros, joint, ros-kinetic, state, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use STOMP with [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/moveit_commander_scripting/moveit_commander_scripting_tutorial.html). I want to plan a path with STOMP using a relative command for the endeffector. I'm trying to execute the following command to achieve this:

> go x 0.5

I found this command in the help function, it is not described in the tutorial.
It can only handle the goal = c command and change the goal[wrist_number] = 1.0 command. (see tutorial)
I want to go left/right with the endeffector and this is **working just fine in OMPL planning.**
The following error is received when executing "go left 0.5"

> [ERROR] [1545234226.341963715]: STOMP: Can only handle joint space goals.

Why is it not working with STOMP?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311090/stomp-planner:-can-only-handle-joint-space-goals/) by [DieterWuytens](https://answers.ros.org/users/38350/dieterwuytens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most recent source version of STOMP can now plan to [cartesian goals](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_moveit/pull/46) so feel free to try that out, report any issues in github if you encounter any.  I'm not familiar with the moveit commander tool but it looks like it builds a cartesian goal based on the inputs you provide to it.  STOMP was only able to take joint goals and so you had to use IK to convert your cartesian goal request into a joint one.

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2018-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DieterWuytens](https://answers.ros.org/users/38350/dieterwuytens/) on 2018-12-19**:
After update i get this while executing "go x 0.5" --> Invalid Trajectory: start point deviates from current robot state more than 0.01 joint 'arm2_tele_joint': expected: 0, current: 0.5805

Already set allowed_start_tolerance_ = 0; in trajectory_execution_manager.cpp Do i need to do a catkin clean?